# slide in caption popping up in the wrong div

Tags: html, css, divide

I am still learning CSS and am having a confusing issue surrounding having a slide-in caption appear inside a different div element. When I have the caption slide in on its own without editing the properties of the image behind it, it works just fine but when I edit it in my webpage to have it fit better the captions all pop-up at the bottom of the background div.

[THIS](https://css-tricks.com/examples/SlideinCaptions/) is what the figure does on its own or when I do not edit it, but if you look at the code below something is causing this slide-in to pop-up in a different div and I cannot figure out what it is.

CSS:

```
html, body {
              margin: 0px;
              padding: 0;
              border: 0;
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
            }
            .background-image {
              left: 0;
              top: 0;
              z-index: 1;
              display: block;
              background-image: url(https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/landscapes/mountains-in-hawaii.png);
              background-size: cover;
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
              -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
              -moz-filter: blur(10px);
              -o-filter: blur(10px);
              -ms-filter: blur(10px);
              filter: blur(10px);
            }
            .bodybox {
              background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.6);
              position:fixed;
              padding:0;
              margin:0;
              border: 0;
              top:0;
              left:0;
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
              z-index:2;
              overflow: scroll;
            }
            .heading {
              background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
              width: 100%;
              height: 10%;
              color: rgb(255,255,255);
              text-align: right;
              margin: 0;
              border: 0;
              padding: 0;
              z-index: 2;
              display: table;
              vertical-align: center;
            }
            .travel_menu {
                background-color: rgba(124,175,192,0.75);
                color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                padding: 0;
                height: 200px;
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 100%;
                z-index: 2;
                text-align: left;
                vertical-align: center;
                display: inline-flex;
            }
            .
            figure {
              z-index: 3;
              display: block;
              position: relative;
              float: left;
              overflow: hidden;
              margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
            }
            figcaption {
              position: absolute;
              background: black;
              background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
              color: white;
              padding: 10px 20px;
              opacity: 0;
              font-size: 15px;
              -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
              -moz-transition:    all 0.6s ease;
              -o-transition:      all 0.6s ease;
            }
            figure:hover figcaption {
              opacity: 1;
            }
            figure:before {
              content: "?";
              position: absolute;
              font-weight: 800;
              background: black;
              background: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
              text-shadow: 0 0 5px white;
              color: black;
              width: 24px;
              height: 24px;
              -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
              -moz-border-radius:    12px;
              border-radius:         12px;
              text-align: center;
              font-size: 14px;
              line-height: 24px;
              -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
              opacity: 0.75;
            }
            figure:hover:before {
              opacity: 0;
            }
            .cap-bot:before { bottom: 10px; left: 10px; }
            .cap-bot figcaption { left: 0; bottom: -30%;}
            .cap-bot:hover figcaption { bottom: 0; }
            .container {
              width: 300px;
              height: 180px;

            }
            .container img {
              width: 100%;
              height: auto;
            }
            h2{
              padding-top: 0;
              margin-top: 0;
            }
            h1{
              padding-top: 0;
              margin-top: 0;
              line-height: 10px;
              padding: 10px 0;
              display:table-cell;
              vertical-align: bottom;
            }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="background-image"></div>
    <body>

    <div class="bodybox">

      <div class="heading"><h1>Travel to ....</h1></div>
      <div class="travel_menu">
        <div class="container">
          <figure class="cap-bot">
            <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/landscapes/fields-of-grain.png" alt="rolling hills of grain.">
            <figcaption>
              Three weeks from now, I will be harvesting my crops. Imagine where you will be, and it will be so. Hold the line! Stay with me! If you find yourself alone, riding in the green fields with the sun on your face, do not be troubled. For you are in Elysium, and you're already dead!
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
         <div class="container">
          <figure class="cap-bot">
            <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/landscapes/fields-of-grain.png" alt="rolling hills of grain.">
            <figcaption>
              Three weeks from now, I will be harvesting my crops. Imagine where you will be, and it will be so. Hold the line! Stay with me! If you find yourself alone, riding in the green fields with the sun on your face, do not be troubled. For you are in Elysium, and you're already dead!
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
         <div class="container">
          <figure class="cap-bot">
            <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/landscapes/fields-of-grain.png" alt="rolling hills of grain.">
            <figcaption>
              Three weeks from now, I will be harvesting my crops. Imagine where you will be, and it will be so. Hold the line! Stay with me! If you find yourself alone, riding in the green fields with the sun on your face, do not be troubled. For you are in Elysium, and you're already dead!
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>    
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `.` before figure see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/hhftbyqk/6/

**change this:**

```
 .
figure {
                  z-index: 3;
                  display: block;
                  position: relative;
                  float: left;
                  overflow: hidden;
                  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
                }
```

**to this:**

```
figure {
                  z-index: 3;
                  display: block;
                  position: relative;
                  float: left;
                  overflow: hidden;
                  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
                }
```

Comment: I have no idea how that little typo managed to do it, but that did seem to solve the problem. Nice catch! Thanks for the help!